# create a PDF catalog from image magick and php?

Tags: php, imagemagick

- I have a set of 10 jpegs.
- I need to generate **1 SINGLE PDF** of these 10 images using PDF. 
  (1 page = 1 jpeg)

Final result must be a PDF.

**Can imagemagick php extension help me with that ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. Sample code:

```
<?php
$files = array(realpath('t1.jpg'), realpath('t2.jpg'));

$image = new Imagick($files);

$image->setImageFormat('pdf');

$image->writeImages(__DIR__ . '/file.pdf', true);
```

The second parameter of [`Imagick::writeImages()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimages.php) controls if the resulting output is joined into one file.

*Footnote: At least on windows, Imagick needs to be used with absolute paths.*

Comment: @user300675 Strange. Did you use the code example as is? What platform are you on?

Answer (score 0):

```
convert -density 150 -size 1239x1754 xc:white -density 150 *test.jpg -gravity center -composite test.pdf
```

Comment: is that for 1 page only ???
How do I specify the images to be converted ? 
let say my images are image1.jpg, image2.jpg... image10.jpg and they should be added in that order or course.

Comment: This is not PHP, it's shell.

Comment: Please add explanation along with code samples to explain what you are suggesting.